# Python dictionary key error.. big mess of dictionaries in dictionaries in lists

Tags: python, debugging

This is kind of convoluted, so if I'm missing out on an easy construct for this, please let me know :)

I'm analysing the results of some matching experiments.  At the end game, I want to be able to query things such as `experiments[0]["cat"]["cat"]`, which yields the number of times "cat" was matched against "cat".  Conversely, I could do `experiments[0]["cat"]["dog"]`, when the first query was a cat and the match attempt was a dog.

The following is my code to populate this structure:

```
    # initializing the first layer, a list of dictionaries.
    experiments = []
    for assignment in assignments:
        match_sums = {}
        experiments.append(match_sums)


for i in xrange(len(classes)):
        for experiment in xrange(len(experiments)):
            # experiments[experiment][classes[i]] should hold a dictionary,
            # where the keys are the things that were matched against classes[i], 
            # and the value is the number of times this occurred.
            experiments[experiment][classes[i]] = collections.defaultdict(dict)

            # matches[experiment][i] is an integer for what the i'th match was in an experiment.
            # classes[j] for some integer j is the string name of the i'th match. could be "dog" or "cat".
            experiments[experiment][classes[i]][classes[matches[experiment][i]]] += 1
            total_class_sums[classes[i]] = total_class_sums.get(classes[i], 0) + 1

    print experiments[0]["cat"]["cat"]
    exit()
```

So clearly this is a bit convoluted.  And I'm getting a value of "1" for the last match, rather than a full dictionary at `experiments[0]["cat"]`.  Have I approached this wrong?  What could the bug here be?  Sorry for the craziness  and thanks for any possible help!

Comment: You MUST use dictionaries? Wouldn't it be easier to go OOP on this one?

Comment: @favoretti perhaps... Though it's not immediately clear what kind of objects would simplify this.  I can't change the original data format (the classes list or the matches list)

Comment: You're code looks like it should work correctly -- you only define the first dictionary as a defaultdict so getting '1' from `experiments[0]["cat"]` seems strange... if you drop the specific experiment assignments do you still get a value of '1' from `experiments[0]["cat"]`?

Comment: Please fix identation. It't not clear wheither print and exit are inside first loop or not

Comment: Also it's strange. Why you should use dict of dicts? In the code you are creating defaultdict and always putting single value in it

Comment: You could init your list more easily like this: `experiments = [{} for _ in xrange(len(assignments))]`

Comment: @Odomontois print and exit are outside of the first loop.  Weird that that occurred.  I should be creating more than a single value inside the defaultdict... and that would be my bug, thanks for pointing that out.  Now how to fix it is another story..

Comment: @Jim I think you already have a mess before this code runs, judging by the need to do `classes[matches[experiment][i]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

- Dictionary keys can be tuples; and
- If you're counting things, use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  (You can use `defaultdict(int)`, but `Counter` is more useful.)

So, instead of

```
experiments[experiment][classes[i]][classes[matches[experiment][i]]] += 1
```

write

```
experiments = Counter()
...
experiments[experiment, classes[i], classes[matches[experiment][i]]] += 1
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question, but I have a feeling it should end up saying something even simpler, like `experiments[experiment_index, cls, value] += 1`, in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I just trying to guess your needs, so i tried to change order of your dimensions.

```
for className, classIdx in enumerate(classes):
    experiment = collections.defaultdict(list)
    experiments[className] = experiment
    for assignment,assignmentIdx in enumerate(assignments):
        counterpart = classes[matches[assignmentIdx][classIdx]]
        experiment[counterpart].append((assignment,assignmentIdx))

print(len(experiments["cat"]["cat"]), len(experiments["cat"]))
```